# SQL: return string describing user category based on a field

Tags: sql

The idea is to get in the result a new column describing the user "category". This category could for example be "under18","normal","over65" based on user age.

That is, for each user in my table I want to get as result its ID and this description in a column called "category".

How would you proceed? I need this because the data will later go to a JSON object and to a ExtJS grid for visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At query level this can be done with `CASE` expression:

```
select
  user_id,
  case when age < 18 then 'under18'
       when age <=65 then 'normal'
       when age > 65 then 'over65'
       else null end as category
from
  Users
```

However i would recommend to move this from query level to application level. You already have application logic to construct JSON from the dataset, this would be a more appropriate place to generate category name from age value.

Answer (score 4):

As your category is data derived from existing data, the use of a new column in the database for it should be discouraged. Instead, you could just add a case statement to your database query to work out the category as required or put it into a view in the database.

The query would look something like this:

```
select
    ...
    case when Age < 18 then 'under18'
         when Age > 65 then 'over65'
         else 'normal' end AS Age_Category
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS supports it, I would create a UDF (user defined function) that passes in the age from your table and returns category.  This has the advantage of being reusable and a little cleaner.  If this is for one query only just use the `CASE` statement.

Comment: One problem with using a UDF is that it incurs an overhead each time it needs to be called. For complex categories, however, they can be the only way.

Comment: Does that case statement syntax actually work? and if so in which dbms's?

Comment: My bad, you can only do it the way I did when you are comparing a value exactly, not when using less than or greater than.  That is how I usually write them when doing straight equality tests since it keeps them a little shorter.

Comment: As for UDFs, I agree there is some overhead but if this was part of a big complex system, it would be a lot easier to maintain when adding a new category "40 somethings" :-)